# Can't load tensorflow (tf-agent) saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am creating a tf-agent DqnAgent in the following code:

```
tf_agent = dqn_agent.DqnAgent(
    train_env.time_step_spec(),
    train_env.action_spec(),
    q_network=q_net,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    td_errors_loss_fn=dqn_agent.element_wise_squared_loss,
    train_step_counter=train_step_counter
```

)

During the training loop I am saving this model with

```
tf.saved_model.save(tf_agent, saved_models_path)
```

Once trained, I want to load saved model with

```
if tf.saved_model.contains_saved_model(saved_models_path):
    tf_agent = tf.saved_model.load(saved_models_path)
```

This code will load the saved model only if the folder in `saved_path` contains one, the functions `contains_saved_model(saved_models_path)` returns `True`, so the model is loaded, but there is an excetion and the program crashes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/claudino/Projetos/dino-tf-agents/dino_ia/model/agent.py", line 50, in <module>
        tf_agent = tf.saved_model.load(saved_models_path)
    File "/home/claudino/Projetos/dino-tf-agents/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 408, in load
        return load_internal(export_dir, tags)
    File "/home/claudino/Projetos/dino-tf-agents/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 432, in load_internal
        export_dir)
    File "/home/claudino/Projetos/dino-tf-agents/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 58, in __init__
        self._load_all()
    File "/home/claudino/Projetos/dino-tf-agents/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 168, in _load_all
        slot_variable = optimizer_object.add_slot(
    AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'add_slot'

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

I navigated tensorflow code but couldn't find the problem. Anyone can help me?

I am using `tf-agents-nightly` because google's colaboratory source code don't work on `tf-agents` "stable" version (I am not sure tf-agents is really stable), and tryed the code with `tensorflow` 1.3 and `2.0.0-beta0`, same problem occurs.

Comment: It has been a while since the question is asked but for the future queries; [PolicySaver](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/blob/2951a8c68fb8e6b9a390091cc2a47eb8f35e2b08/tf_agents/docs/python/tf_agents/policies/policy_saver/PolicySaver.md) class is used for saving a TF-Agents policy, now. Developers are [planning to add it to a tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/issues/186), but it is not done yet.

Comment: Is there a difference between checkpoints saving, model saving, and policy saving?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried TensorFlow 2.7? That usually helps with this issue.

Something else that worked for me was to load the model this way (This assumes the model is a `keras`/`tf.keras` model):

```
try:
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_dir)
except:
  load_options = tf.saved_model.LoadOptions(experimental_io_device= '/job:localhost')
  model = tf.saved_model.load(model_dir, options= load_options)
```

The try clause will lead to an exception, because `load_model()` requires a `keras_metadata.pb` file, which is absent when you save models with `saved_model.save()`.

However, running that clause will somehow make `tf.saved_model.load()` run without any problems. There's probably some sort of interaction happening in the background that I don't really understand, but it works for me and the '`no attribute add_slot`' error doesn't come up.